# The "PUT method is not supported for this route" error comes up after jquery ajax update

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I update the database with jquery ajax and print "success/failure" with alert according to the return value. The product update is successful, but the message "failed" appears on the screen and I get the error "The PUT method is not supported for this route".

**My jquery:**

```
$('#policies_button').on('click', function () {
        $('#ShiftAddModal').modal('hide');
        var id = $('#select_policies').val();
        var url = $('#selected_option_' + id).attr('data-url');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            data: $('#bulkupdate_form').serialize(),
            url: url,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    $('#ShiftAddModal').modal('hide');
                    alertify.success('Başarılı: İzin kuralı ataması başarılı bir şekilde gerçekleşmiştir.');
                } else if (response.error) {
                    alertify.error(response.error);
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alertify.error('Hata: Sayfanızı yenileyerek tekrar deneyiniz.');
            }
        });
    });
```

**url:**

```
<option id="selected_option_{{$item->policies_id}}"
                                                value="{{$item->policies_id}}"
                                                data-url="{{route('personnel.update',$item->policies_id)}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
```

**coming here by route:**

```
protected function policiesAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    foreach ($this->model->get() as $item) {
        $action = Actions::personnel_policies_update(
            $this->model,
            $request->get('personnel_name' . $item->personnel_id),
            $id
        );
    }
    return $action;
}


public static function personnel_policies_update(Model $model,$personnel_id,$id){
    $fields = array(
        'policies_id' => $id,
    );
    $model->where('personnel_id',$personnel_id)->update($fields);
    return redirect()->to(route('bulkupdate.index'))->with('success','Başarılı: Personel ataması başarıyla gerçekleşti!');
}
```

Comment: Seems you're not defined a PUT route for the requested ```url``` . Try to change the method to POST on ajax request, (i.e. ```type: 'POST'```)

Comment: Route::resource('personnel' => \App\Http\Controllers\backend\PersonnelController::class);

Comment: Ok, change the method to POST and inject a csrf_token, or add it in the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the method to POST.

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   data: $('#bulkupdate_form').serialize(),
   url: url,
   ...
});
```

Considering that csrf token is not been included in the headers yet, you must include it on form data:

```
<form id="bulkupdate_form" ... >
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <!-- or simply -->
    @csrf        
</form>
```